# How to use MOXy JSON serializer/deserializer on android as a REST client?

Tags: android, json, rest, jackson, moxy

### How can I have MOXy JSON serializer/deserializer on android as a REST client?

I tried EclipseLink and Jersey client, but no success.

I had **Jackson** with **resteasy-mobile**, and worked well, but I have Jersey server with **MOXy**, and Jackson and MOXy has some conflict, like in `Map<Key, Value>`

MOXy:

```
"map":{
    "entry":[
        {
            "key":{Key...},
            "value":{Value...}
        },
        {
            "key":{Key...},
            "value":{Value...}
        },
        {
            "key":{Key...},
            "value":{Value...}
        },
        {
            "key":{Key...},
            "value":{Value...}
        },
    ]
}
```

Jackson:

```
"map": {
    "Key.toString()" : {Value...},
    "Key.toString()" : {Value...},
    "Key.toString()" : {Value...},
    "Key.toString()" : {Value...},
}
```

---

I tried EclipseLink:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Trip.class);

            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            unmarshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", "application/json");

            unmarshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.json.include-root", false);
            StreamSource source = new StreamSource("my.rest.url/transport/getTrip/ID");
            JAXBElement<Trip> jaxbElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal(source, Trip.class);

            System.out.println(jaxbElement.getValue().getId());

            Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
            marshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.json.include-root", false);
            marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, System.out);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}.execute();
```

maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I cant use this, because this needs class files from `javax.xml.stream` and `javax.xml.bind` which cannot overwrite in android. I tried JarJar:

```
rule javax.xml.stream.** hu.fehergeri13.javax.xml.stream.@1
rule javax.xml.bind.** hu.fehergeri13.javax.xml.bind.@1
rule javax.xml.namespace.** hu.fehergeri13.javax.xml.namespace.@1
rule javax.xml.XMLConstants hu.fehergeri13.javax.xml.XMLConstants
rule javax.persistence.** hu.fehergeri13.javax.persistence.@1
```

But It needs so many package, It ends always a classNotFound exception.

I also tried Jersey Client but got the same problems.

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        clientConfig.register(MOXyJsonProvider.class);

        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
        
        URI uri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://my.rest.url/").build();
        System.out.println(uri.toString());

        WebTarget target = client.target(uri.toString());
        
        TransportSvc resource = WebResourceFactory.newResource(TransportSvc.class, target);

        Trip trip = resource.getTrip("B078821013");
        System.out.println(trip);

        return null;
    }
}.execute();
```